# Find the length $L$ of the catenary

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, arc-length

$C$: $y = \cosh(x)$, $\,\log(2) \leq x \leq \log(3)$.

I did arrive at the problem until $\sinh b$, but I don't know how to continue. Should it be $\sinh(\log(3))$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What did you try? How did you come up with that answer? Have a look at [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math on this site and elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the arc-length formula with $f(x)=\cosh(x)$. Then the length of the curve on $(\log(2),\log(3))$ is
$$L=\int_{\log(2)}^{\log(3)}\sqrt{1+[f^\prime(x)]^2}\,dx = \int_{\log(2)}^{\log(3)}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}\,dx=\int_{\log(2)}^{\log(3)}\cosh(x)\,dx.$$
Evaluating this integral
$$L=\sinh(\log(3))-\sinh(\log(2)).$$
Note that in the above we have used the fact that $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1.$ I hope that this answers your question!